# Why is istream::operator>>(char& val) missing?

Tags: c++, istream

Looking at all the [`operator>>()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) functions supported by `std::istream` in `C++98`, I was surprised to find that there is no

```
istream& operator>> (char& val);
```

Why is that overload not included in the standard?

**P.S.** I noticed that it is not supported in `C++11` either.

Comment: It's a non member. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/